# null snapshot in FutureBuilder when returning map

Tags: flutter, dart, future

i cant figure out why i always got null return in future builder while i'm sure there should be a value

```
//global variables
Map<String,bool> students;
List<String> studentsList ;
List<bool> studentsCheck ;

FutureBuilder(
  future: GetInfoFromBackEnd(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.hasData?
    CustomScrollView(....some not important widgets here....):CircularProgressIndicator();

},)
Future GetInfoFromBackEnd() async {
students = {
  'this info should be taken from backend0':false,
  'this info should be taken from backend0':false,
  'this info should be taken from backend0':false,
  'this info should be taken from backend0':false,
  'this info should be taken from backend0':false,
  };
studentsList = students.keys;
studentsCheck = students.values;
return students;
 }
```

i have a workaround for this code but i need to understand why this is hapening and what's going on

Comment: what is null? `snapshot.data`?

Comment: i used your example and neither snapshot, nor hasData is null.

Comment: btw if you want to test with mock data in a map, you need to have at least different keys. Otherwise you will end up with just one element in the map. And i would make the code more type safe by adding types to AsyncSnapshot<Map> and Future<Map>. Makes coding easier and you will have intellisense in the editor.

Comment: @pskink yes it is snapshot data

Comment: Marc ok wait a minute i will edit the code and try

Comment: try just for testing to change `students = {` to `var students = {` and remove `//global variables
Map<String,bool> students;`

Comment: @pskink please check my answer to the question

Comment: you dont need those `studentsList` and `studentsCheck` fields - instead you have a `snapshot.data` - just use it

Comment: Of course he doesnt need that variables. Thats why i left them out in the answer. But anyway

Answer (score 0):

Provided the basic HelloWorld Flutter example with your code included. I added a delay to the future so that the ProgressIndicator shows up for two seconds. Works like intended to me:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  Map<String, bool> students;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
          future: GetInfoFromBackEnd(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Map> snapshot) {
            return snapshot.hasData
                ? new Text(snapshot.data.toString())
                : new CircularProgressIndicator();
          }),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<Map> GetInfoFromBackEnd() async {
    return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
      students = {
        'this info should be taken from backend0': false,
        'this info should be taken from backend1': false,
        'this info should be taken from backend2': false,
        'this info should be taken from backend3': false,
        'this info should be taken from backend4': false,
      };
      return students;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: the solution was to show you that it works without your wrong assignments. And that it never was a NPE in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was not in the FutureBuilder or in the map, actually when i was trying to get the students Map values and keys each in List it breaks the Future and prevent it from returning the corret value so i got null in snapshot.data; and here is how i fixed it :

```
studentsList = students.keys.toList();
studentsCheck = students.values.toList();
return students;
```

P.S. : error was `type '_CompactIterable<String>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>'`

Comment: thats why i left out the keys and values assignments in the example program. ;-)

Comment: yep but i need keys and values :)

Comment: @evals you dont need those `studentsList` and `studentsCheck` fields - instead you have a `snapshot.data` - just use it

Comment: @pskink i need it in other widgets below out of this class , thats why i made it global variables

Comment: @evals so place your "other widgets" as children of `FutureBuilder`